# Flashing Lenovo Vibe K5 to Stock ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, lenovo, stock-rom

Lenovo Vibe K5 is up and running in CM 13. But, I need to flash stock ROM on it. Now, I have tried to flash with TWRP, but that didn't worked for stock firmwares. I have seen multiple tutorials, in that, they are using QPST and flashing it easily. While I am having problem, because my device shows as non Qualcomm device. It shows as `RELINK HS-USB QDLoader` instead of `Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader`. I have installed the Qualcomm drivers correctly.

[image: issue]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done it. So i am sharing with all of you, you should turn off your internet while doing all these steps , because when you press and hold **vol up + down button** and insert usb cable, it automatically downloads Relink driver because of running internet in the background and even if you uninstall and reinstall those drivers it wouldn't work unless you format it .